# Swift Enums, `OR` equalization

Tags: swift, refactoring, code-readability

How to check if enum is equal to the one of possibility cases. Is there better solution than:

```
[.orderedAscending, .orderedSame].contains(Calendar.current.compare(date, to: range.from, toGranularity: .day))
```

In my opinion it is a little bit unclear and I looking for better.

#### Edit:

According to @Martin_R answer of course in this example I can do negative equalization:

```
Calendar.current.compare(date1, to: date2, toGranularity: .day) != .orderedDescending
```

`ComparisonResult` used here is only an example. I looking for more general solution answer. For example, what if enum would be have more cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to perform Switch on the results this way:

```
let result = alendar.current.compare(date1, to: date2, toGranularity: .day)

switch result {
   case orderedAscending:
     // actions
   case orderedSame:
     //actions
   default: break
}
```

This is more readable and clearer

Answer (score 0):

There are only three possible comparison results:

```
public enum ComparisonResult : Int {
    case orderedAscending
    case orderedSame
    case orderedDescending
}
```

therefore

```
Calendar.current.compare(date1, to: date2, toGranularity: .day) != .orderedDescending
```

can be used to check if the second date is on the same or a later day
than the first date.

Comment: Tnx for relay. I wrong asked the question. I looking for more general solution. I edited my questions. I apologize for the confusion.